# Error installing InHouse or AdHoc apps

Tags: ios, certificate, xcode7, code-signing-certificate

I can create AdHoc or InHouse IPA files, but there's something wrong with the signing process, as when someone tries to install them, they always get:

```
Mar  8 11:52:47 iPhone installd[2637] <Error>: 0x16e12f000 bom_fatal_error_handler: BOMCopier signaled fatal error: Couldn't read pkzip local header
Mar  8 11:52:47 iPhone installd[2637] <Error>: 0x16e12f000 +[MIBOMWrapper extractZipArchiveAtURL:toURL:withError:]: 145: Could not extract archive (Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=0 "Undefined error: 0")
```

I think it's a problem of my KeyChain certificates, used when signing and creating the final IPA, but don't know what...

I've tried to reinstall XCode (7.2.1), all my p12 certificates, the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Intermediate Certificate, everything...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an FTP Client with ASCII transfer type. When switched to Binary transfer type the IPA could be installed.